# Check content of file and add string if not exists

Tags: string, file, powershell, insert, compare

I want to do the following:

I need to check the content of a (text) file. If a defined string is not there, it has to be inserted on a specific position.
I.e.:

My textfile is a configuration file with different sections, example:

```ini
[default]
name=bob
alias=alice
foo=bar
example=value

[conf]
name=value
etc=pp
```

I want to check if the string “foo=bar” and “example=value” exists in this file. If not, it has to get inserted, but I can't just append the new lines, since they have to be in the certain (here [default]) section and not to the end of the file. The position within the section doesn’t matter.

I tried with the following PowerShell script, which actually just looks for a definitely existing string and adds the new lines after it. Therefore I can make sure that the new lines get inserted in the right section, but I can't make sure that they won't be doubled, since my script doesn't check if they already exist.

```
$InputFile = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Path\to\file.ini"

$find = [regex]::Escape("alias=alice")

$addcontent1 = "foo=bar"
$addcontent2 = " example=value `n"
$InputFileData = Get-Content $InputFile
$matchedLineNumber = $InputFileData |
                     Where-Object{$_ -match $find} |
                     Select-Object -Expand ReadCount

$InputFileData | ForEach-Object{
    $_
    if ($_.ReadCount -eq ($matchedLineNumber)) {
        $addcontent1
        $addcontent2        
    }
} | Set-Content $InputFile
```

Comment: You have what's called a `ini` file. There are Windows APIs for handling these. (Hint: Search for a PowerShell module that can handle `ini` files.)

Comment: Even without that, an INI parser isn't that hard to implement. I expect there are several examples to be found here. You'll want to parse the file, because INI is a structured format, and you probably need to add your key/value pair to the right section.

Comment: [use-powershell-to-work-with-any-ini-file](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/08/20/use-powershell-to-work-with-any-ini-file/)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Bill_Stewart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2102693/bill-stewart), [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) and [LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings) there are multiple modules to work with `.ini` files available in the web.

Let's take [this one](https://lipkau.github.io/PsIni/) for example. Once you download it and import you can see how it imports your file (I removed `foo=bar` to demonstrate):

```
PS C:\SO\51291727> $content = Get-IniContent .\file.ini
PS C:\SO\51291727> $content

Name                           Value
----                           -----
default                        {name, alias,  example}
conf                           {name, etc}
```

From here what you want to do is pretty simple - check if key exists and if not - add:

```
if ($content.default.foo -ne 'bar') {
   $content.default.foo='bar'
}
```

Verify that the value has been inserted:

```
PS C:\SO\51291727> $content.default

Name                           Value
----                           -----
name                           bob
alias                          alice
example                        value
foo                            bar
```

And export:

```
$content | Out-IniFile .\out.ini
```